# Mule Logger does not resolve #[payload] or flow variable

Tags: logging, mule

```
 The logger statements always logs #[payload} or message.payload. In  other words the variables are never resolved.
```

Why is the logger always printing the variables unresolved?

```
 log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R
```

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
      log4j.appender.R.File=${mule.home}/logs/App.log
      log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB

```
  log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10
  log4j.appender.R.append=true
  log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n
  log4j.logger.org.apache=WARN, R
  log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
```

log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.factory=WARN, R
       log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans.
       GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor=ERROR, R
      log4j.logger.org.springframework.context.support=WARN, R
       log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR, R

```
  log4j.logger.org.mule=DEBUG, R
  log4j.logger.com.mulesoft=DEBUG, R
   log4j.logger.com.mulesoft.mule.cluster.boot=ERROR, R
  log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=WARN, R
  log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters=WARN, R
  log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils=WARN, R
  log4j.logger.org.mule.config.spring.parsers.assembly=OFF,R



     <flow name="MainFlow"
     processingStrategy="synchronous">
      <vm:inbound path="in.queue"/>
      <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            path="order.validation" doc:name="VM" />
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            path="order.validation.result" doc:name="VM" />
      </request-reply>


     <set-property propertyName="validationValue" value="#

      [message.inboundProperties.validationResult]" 
          doc:name="Set Validation Result" />

     <logger
       message="Result -mesage.inboundProperties.validationResult]"
       level="INFO"
         doc:name="Validation Variable" />
     <logger
    message="Message Payload ==&gt;  #[flowVars.validationValue]"
    level="INFO"
    doc:name="Logger" />



      <logger
      message="Message Payload ==&gt; #[message.payload] or #[payload]"
     level="INFO"
      doc:name="Logger" />




     <catch-exception-strategy doc:name=" App Exception">
        <logger
            message="Main Processing flow - #[message] :: 
                   ExceptionSummary::= #[exception.summaryMessage]"
            level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"  />
      </catch-exception-strategy>
      </flow>



  <flow name="Order.Validation.flow" >
        <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
            path="order.validation" doc:name="VM" />
         <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="ValidateOrderBean" />
        </component>
         <set-property propertyName="validationResult" 
            value="#[flowVars.result]" doc:name="Property"/>
  </flow>
```

Comment: This doesn't look familiar. So, I ask "What did you change?". Did you write this log4j configuration yourself? If so, then your question isn't a Mule one. 1) Is this your entire log configuration? 2) Why do you have log4j configurations in a Mule flow?

Comment: @David Whitehurst, agreed.  When using the default mule log4j2 configurations base I have not see logger fail to resolve payload or flowVars.  This would appear to be an issue with log4j configuration.

Comment: Post your Mule config and your log4j config (both in their entirety) separately. Your chances of getting an answer will be better. Maybe this is Spring context issue and Mule does have a problem. Anyhow, post both your Mule config and log4j config separately and in their entirety.

Comment: Yes, I did write the log4j config file.. I just posted the log4j.properties file to see if anything looked out of place. The flow is posted to show the logging been done.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating string insides MEL,  like this -

```
<logger
      message="#['Message Payload ==>' + payload]"
     level="INFO"
      doc:name="Logger" />
```